# How to bootstrap socialengine?

Tags: api, zend-framework, bootstrapping, socialengine

I need to use some functionality exposed by an SE model as part of an AJAX call. Something like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once("application/modules/Advancedarticles/Model/Artarticle.php");
$id = $_GET['id'] or die("Malformed instruction");
$article = new AdvancedArticle($id);
$shares = array(
    'twitter'=>$article->twitterShareCount,
    'facebook'=>$article->facebookShareCount,
);
echo json_encode($shares);
?>
```

No need for routing or any of that jazz.

What's the bare minimum needed to bootstrap SE in this way?

Answer (score 3):

When you're developing for SocialEngine or any other platforms it's best to follow the standard structure of that platform. In SocialEngine first you create a module from the developer SDK provided by SocialEngine. You can access the SDK from SocialEngine's Package Manager.

After installing the new module you need to create a controller. This controller will fetch the data from the model and outputs it as JSON.

I'm guessing Advancedarticles is a plugin from SEAO so there should be an **advancedarticles_article** Model Item or something similar already defined in Advancedarticles plugin's manifest. You can check the item name in :

```
application/modules/Advancedarticles/settings/manifest.php
```

Lets say your newly created module name is **Myapi** and your controller is located  at :

```
application/modules/Myapi/controllers/ArticleController.php
```

Controller code :

```
<?php

 class Myapi_ArticleController extends Core_Controller_Action_Standard
 {

    public function sharesAction()
    {
        $id = $this->_getParam('id');

        $article = Engine_Api::_()->getItem('advancedarticles_article', $id);

        $shares = array(
            'twitter'=>$article->twitterShareCount,
            'facebook'=>$article->facebookShareCount,
        );

        $this->_helper->json($shares);
    }

 }
```

Then you call it with :

```
http://localhost/myapi/article/shares/?id=XXX
```

Comment: @DanielJames fyi the etiquette is to mark an answer with a green checkbox - it helps Stack Overflow algorithms and awards points to the author.

Comment: I am aware of that but as you can see, the submitted answer doesn't actually answer the question. It is also etiquette not to use SO as a discussion forum, of course. See: Stackoverflow is not a forum (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum)

Comment: If it doesn't answer your question, then you should point out what is unclear. From your own comment, I have assumed it did. Additionally, re-reading both question and Ali's answer, I believe that it does indeed address it adequately.

Comment: @DanielJames Wasn't my answer clear, concise and to the point as you said it yourself? If something is missing let me know and I will add it to my answer.